# COMO FAZER UM BOTAO APARECER SOMENTE PARA O ADMINISTRADOR

Tags: android, ionic, ionic4

Alguém poderia me ajudar? eu estou tentando fazer uma pagina de administrador mas estou com dificuldades, pois qualquer um que logar no aplicativo, vai ver o botão (ADD PRODUTOS) e o (Deletar produtos), pois ficam visíveis, fiz uma API com o Firebase e já consegui deixar as rotas mais seguras, pois somente com o id de quem criou o produto pode deletar e alterar, mas como fazer os botoes ficarem visíveis somente com o ID do adm ?

ABAIXO UM POUCO DO CODIGO:

## Nossos Sabores

```
    <ion-label color="favorite-rosa">
      <p>{{ product.name }}</p>
      <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
      <p>{{ product.createdAt | date: 'short' }}</p>
      <ion-note slot="end" color="primary" *ngIf="product.price">{{ product.price | currency: 'BRL' }}</ion-note>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-badge color="favorite-rosa" >Fazer Pedido</ion-badge>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item-options side="end">
    <ion-item-option color="danger" (click)="deleteProduct(product.id)">
      <ion-icon slot="top" name="trash"></ion-icon>
      Excluir
    </ion-item-option>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

Sair

```
    <ion-col size="6">
      <ion-button routerLink="/details" expand="block">
        Add produto
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça com ngIf, segue exemplo do botão aparecendo para usuário do tipo administrar e o outro só aparecendo para quem não é administrador:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf = "usuario === 'Administrador' ">
<ion-button>
</ion-button>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf = "usuario !== 'Administrador' ">
<ion-button>
</ion-button>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: teria que criar uma interface ou uma variavel ?

Comment: pode ser uma variável

Answer (score -1):

Teria como fazer isso para um URL  com Web view, mostra apenas esse texto quando ele estiver na página inicial e as demais não mostra